# Recurrence solving by substitution

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, substitution, recurrence

```
T(n) = { 0                     If n = 0
       { T(square root n) + 1  If n > 0
```

I am trying to solve that by using substitution

My guess: `O(lg lg n)`

By using induction

```
T(n) =  c lg lg n
T(n) =< c (lg lg square root n) + 1
```

Since `square root n = n^1/2 =< c(1/2 lg lg n) + 1`

I am not able to continue this part to get `lg lg n` and I saw many solutions which use powers. Is there other way?

Can any one draw a recursion tree to help me understand?

```
1
||
n^1/2
||
n^1/4
||
n^1/8

T(n) = 1 + .......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to understand this is with powers of `2` as many other answers say, but, to continue the step you mentioned, suppose `T(n) = lg lg n` (ignoring the constant as this is an exact answer).

Then we have:

```
T(sqrt(n)) = lg lg (sqrt(n)) = lg (1/2 * lg (n))
= lg (2^(-1) * lg(n))
= -1 + lg lg (n)
= -1 + T(n)
```

So as you see, `T(n) = T(sqrt(n)) + 1`